# Visual Studio - Can I export templates via command line?

Tags: vs-extensibility, visual-studio-templates

Is the "Export Template" functionality available from a command line anywhere? I checked the command line arguments for both MSBuild.exe and devenv.exe and didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to: Create a Project Template Using the Projectgen.exe Command-Line Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175876.aspx)

Comment: I don't find Projectgen.exe for Visual Studio 2015. Is there an equivalent for this version?

Comment: @DheerajV.S.Have you got a solution for this?